# HTTPCLIENT does not exist? Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath, httpclient

I am trying to import:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;
```

But I am being told these do not exist?

I downloaded:
`httpclient-4.0.1.jar` and `httpmime-4.0.1.jar`

... and placed these in the same folder as my .java files that are trying to use httpclient.

Any ideas?

I still cannot get it to work... Within the folder "Libraries" I have: apache-mime4j0.6.jar commons-codec-1.3.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar httpclient-4.0.1.jar httpcore-4.0.1.jar httpmime-4.0.1.jar For the java file properties it has: compile classpath runtime classpath boot classpath In each of those, it seems to refer to the jars I have imported. Still getting does not exist. :-(

I have tried to do this in Eclipse too and now those files appear in "Referenced libraries" however it still doesn't work. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two jars you have mentioned need to be placed in the classpath of the project in Netbeans, not in the source directory.

In my Netbeans 6.7.1 on Mac, in the Prjects tab, you cna right click on the project and select Properties.  That will bring up the project properties dialog.  In there, choose the libraries item from the tree on the left.  From there, choose the Add Jar/Folder in the Compile view.  To add the jar to your project, use the chooser to locate it and then select it.

EDIT:

I have just downloaded the HTTPClient package and I think I see the problem:

in 4.0.1, the package structure is not as you have it defined.  Instead of:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;
```

use:

```
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;
import org.apache.http.client.params.HttpMethodParams;
```

Comment: OK - Within Projects in netbeans, I managed to add httpclient, etc to "Libraries".

I am still getting "does not exist"...

Comment: Can you for your help on this!  It is appreciated.

I still cannot get it to work though...

Within the folder "Libraries" I have:
apache-mime4j0.6.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
httpclient-4.0.1.jar
httpcore-4.0.1.jar
httpmime-4.0.1.jar

For the java file properties it has:
compile classpath

runtime classpath

boot classpath

In each of those, it seems to refer to the jars I have imported.  Still getting does not exist. :-(

Comment: Yes that seems to fix that problem!  Wow, thank you!

I have been following this resource and it must be out of date: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html

I am trying: HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

But for HttpClient(); it gives that it is "abstract, cannot be instantiated".

Comment: Ah, the tutorial is for httpclient 3.  Dang!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, press Ctrl + Shift + O to organize your imports.  This will look for all unknown classes on the classpath and try to import them.  You can also place your cursor on a class name and press Ctrl + Shift + M to attempt to import that single class.  This is sometimes helpful for class name collision (i.e. if two packages have a HttpClient class, you can click on the desired class).

If the jars are in Referenced Libraries, then they should be on your classpath.  You can verify this by right clicking the project and selecting something like Build Path > Configure Build Path, then click the libraries tab.

Also, you probably have build automatically selected by default, but if you don't, you'll need to build your project.  You may also want to attempt to clear the build path and re-build it.  I've seen my Eclipse get out of synch a few times and this fixed it, albeit somewhat of a fluke.

If you're using Maven, this sort of thing can sometimes occur if you have an incorrect dependency scope (i.e. runtime, or test vs. compile).

For what it's worth, unless you're utilizing the entire package, there is no reason to import an entire package's contents (i.e. import package.*).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that HttpClient has changed his sintaxis from 3 to 4 version... I had same problems that all of you trying to import packages until I found this example:

http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/

This is sample is Android oriented but works on any Java Application!!! Im using netbeans 6.9.1, httpclient-4.1.1.jar, commons-codec-1.4.jar and commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Hope you can solve your problems!!!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and i managed to get the solution. Here it is:

1) Download the org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar.zip file from
   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonshttpclientjar.htm 
   and save it anywhere on your computer.

2) Right click on your NetBeans project and select **Properties**

3) On Project Properties Categories, select **Libraries**

4) Click the Add JAR/Folder button

5) Now browse to the file location where you saved your downloaded org.apache....jar.zip 
   file and click open button.

6) Now the file has been installed, click OK and you are done.

Note that this might require you to restart your netbeans IDE.